# Changing Value of State dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component with following state

```
state = {
    SandD: true,
    Cancellation: false,
    Payments: false,
    EandR: false,
    InternationalShipping: false,
    ExpressDelievery: false
}
```

I want at a time only one selected state to be true and rest to be false. for that I was thinking the following logic

```
currentActiveState = (value) => {
    for ( i=0; i<this.state.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.state[i])
        if(this.state[i] == value) { 
            console.log(this.state[i])
         } else {
            this.setState(this.state[i]: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Here value is the property of the state which need to have a value and rest everything should be false..

For example if Payments is true then everything else should be false..

Can someone help me in fixing the above logic or tell me how I can solve it?

Comment: How do you know which value to set? You are using `i`, which indicates your values are in an array and determined by a position but the actual values you provided are an object with values denoted by property names

Comment: I think you'd be better off with an ENUM to represent your state.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is trying to loop over an object, which does not have a length property. If you decide to take this approach, you should look at Javascript's for-in loop.

Comment: You may consider having a single state property instead that may hold the strings "SandD", "Cancellation", "Payments", etc. This prevents having to manage a bunch of distinct flags that affect the same things. Otherwise, I would use a function that explicitly names and falsifies all properties you listed. By explicitly naming each property to set, you avoid setting other properties to a boolean that you may want to use for other datatypes.

Comment: Roshan, you have a history of not accepting answers. Do you understand how this site works?

Answer (score 2):

Try giving this a shot:

```
currentActiveState = (value) => {
    const newState = {};
    Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => {
        newState[key] = key === value; 
    })
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Comment: @Jayffe Crap. I just cleaned up the spacing from your edit a bit, and it removed you. Feel free to edit again so you can get credit.

Comment: Ok did it, Thanks !